# After migrating to Webpack 2, gulp or webpack-stream causes webpack build to fail

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp, babeljs, webpack-2

After migrating to Webpack 2, using gulp to run webpack with [webpack-stream](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream) seems to cause babel or webpack to throw an error (can't tell where error originates from). Running `webpack` with the config and structure below builds successfully but piping it through gulp and webpack-stream causes this error:

```
Message:
    ./app/app.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/app/app.jsx Unexpected token (11:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (11:1)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1861:32)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/schne482/Code/tralgo/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1796:19)
Details:
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: true
```

What I have done:

- Changed the structure of `webpack.config.js` to obey Webpack 2.
- Moved babel config to separate `.babelrc`. No visible effects.
- Ensured `.babelrc` has correct structure.
- Ensured Webpack points to correct entry file (`./app/app.jsx`) and entry file is processed by loaders.
- Ran babel (`babel ./app/app.jsx`) without webpack using same `.babelrc` and dependencies. Output was correct, no errors.
- Ran webpack without gulp, output was correct.
- Updated relevant packages (babel-core, babel-loader, babel presets, webpack-stream, gulp, etc..).
- Checked for any simple syntax errors.

Here are the relevant files:

#### `gulpfile.js`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
const webpack_config = require('./webpack.config');

function webpack_build_dev() {
  webpack_config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
  return gulp.src('app/app.jsx')
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpack_config), webpack)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
}

gulp.task('webpack:build:dev', gulp.series('clean', webpack_build_dev));
```

#### `./app/app.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const app = (
    <h1>Hello</h1>
);

render(
  app,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

#### `./webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './app'),
  entry: './app.jsx',
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
      modules: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './app'),
          "node_modules",
      ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

#### `./.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

#### `./package.json` (relevant devDependencies):

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issues you are...

Comment: @Chris unfortunately that makes me slightly more at ease, we'll figure this out! I'm going to try a few more things, I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Not at a PC at the moment so can't test this, but can you try:

Change import to:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

Then change render to:

```
ReactDOM.render (
   ...
)
```

Comment: Didn't change anything, nor should it. If that was the case then that would be a bug as that is valid ES6 code.

Comment: Not sure if you have fixed it yet, just tried to recreate with your configuration above and it builds fine, what command are you running that is generating the error?

Comment: Running it through gulp seems to be doing this. I did the same and it builds fine for me also just running webpack. I'll update this when I get the chance, it is definitely gulp or webpack stream.

Comment: It seems the error is about parsing a JSX module using an inappropriate loader or parsing it with no loader as stated in the error logs line 3 and line 4. Changing the imports as stated above seems to not correlate to the error in the logs stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add

```
 "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
```

to your .babelrc file?